# Passing an arraylist to another class

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm fairly new to programming and I'm a bit confused here.  I am trying to pass a filled arraylist to another class. Here's the class where I make the arraylist:

```
public class inventory
{    
    private static ArrayList<engineSpecs> list = new ArrayList<engineSpecs>();
    public inventory()
    {        
        //Instantiates objects of constructor engineSpecs
        engineSpecs astonmartin = new engineSpecs("Aston Martin", "Vanquish", 350000, 11, "Gray",
                                     2015, 565, 457, "automatic");
        engineSpecs ferrari = new engineSpecs ("Ferrari", "458 Italia", 240000, 13, "Red", 2015, 
                                       570, 398, "automatic"); 

        //Adds objects into array list
        list.add(astonmartin);
        list.add(ferrari);   
    }
    public static ArrayList<engineSpecs> getList()
    {
        return list;
    } 
}
```

And here's the class I'm trying to pass the arraylist to:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {        
    inventory inventory = new inventory();
    System.out.println (inventory.getList());
    }
}
```

When I run the main class, it just prints out an empty arraylist. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why is `private static ArrayList<engineSpecs> list` private?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. I got the list with data.

Comment: Also don't see the problem, sorry. Also it should be considered bad style to declare your list static but do the initialization in the constructor. Remove the static keywords from your inventory class, that will work as well.

Comment: Are u sure u are getting empty list....You shud get result like this [Tester.engineSpecs@23fc4bec, Tester.engineSpecs@8dc8569]

Comment: I also would rename all classes to begin with a capital

Comment: Do you want the println statement to display something like [Aston Martin, Ferrari]

Comment: Well it turns out when I pasted my code here, I made a mistake. But my mistake ended up being the solution to my problem! lol Thanks for the help guys! (And I will be sure to capitalize the class names)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default when you print a list it will display it as follows

> [ classname of element of list@HashCode ]

If you want a list to be displayed in a specific way you need to override the toString method of the class which is added to the list. In your case the enginespecs class

Adding a simple toString in engineSpecs class like below will give you a desired result

```
public String toString(){
return name;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

> [Aston Martin, Ferrari]

**NOTE**

In java class names need to begin with capital. And a parameter should be declared static only if you want to use it at the class level

Answer (score 0):

The results will not be null or empty.
It will have entries as well. If you override toString for the class "engineSpecs " you can see the entries of list.

Answer (score 0):

Try decalaring it as instance variable instead of static. and remove static way of accessing the list.